# Count specific characters with a specific condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
>>> data
['abaaabababbbbaaabaab', 'baaabbbbabaabbaabaab']
```

I need to count the number of isolated `b`s. (actually 9 in this example). i.e. if there is a single `b` (previous or next character not b) in the line the variable increase by 1.

Comment: Do you mean how many b's are not next to another b?

Comment: The regex `(?<!b)b(?!b)` will find all isolated `b` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
sum(len(c) == 1 for s in data for c in s.split('a')) # 9
```

This will work only if *all* strings consist of *a* and *b*, otherwise use `re.split`:

```
import re
sum(len(c) == 1 for s in data for c in re.split(r'[^b]{1}', s)) # 9
```

Comment: `{1}` can become `+` for less splits.  Doubt it matters.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> data = ['abaaabababbbbaaabaab', 'baaabbbbabaabbaabaab']
>>> sum(1 for part in data for s in re.findall('[b]+', part) if len(s) == 1)
9
```

You can write a smarter regular expression that will match only the ones you want.  That would allow you to omit `if len(s) == 1`.

**Edit.** A smarter regex is probably not worth it because it is harder to understand:

```
>>> sum(len(re.findall('(?<!b)b(?!b)', part)) for part in data)
9
```

Comment: I've been trying to find a way to match not b or nothing, but this is far easier to understand in my opinion.